# running gulp & express simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp

Set up Gulp, set up node, express. I'm running gulp, it's watching my tasks. Set up express, it's running on port 3001, where Gulp is 3000 by default?

I go to localhost:3000, I see my index.html, I go to localhost:3001 (the express port) and I also see index.html, but without CSS. What is going on here and how can I work with both on one port? Is it possible? Do I just keep gulp and node server running? Very new to js.

Here's files:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hour-hour",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Find the best local happy hours and drink specials near you.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Corey Maret",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.12.3",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "jshint": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
var router = express.Router();

    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    app.listen(3001, function() {
        console.log('I\'m Listening...')
    })
```

gulpfile

```
/* Required */

var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

/* Scripts Task */

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src(['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/js/**/*min.js'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});

/* Sass Task */
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});

/* HTML Task */

gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});

/* Browser-Sync Task */

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
    browserSync.init({
        server:{
            baseDir: "./app/"
        }
    });
});

/* Watch Task */

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.html', ['html']);
})

/* Default */

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'sass', 'html', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Gulp doesn't need to run on a port number.

Comment: nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting. I keep getting a throw error in module.js:341. Error: Cannot find module 'C:\users\corey|desktop\projects\folder\server.js' 

My only problems seems to be getting my css to work...everything else is great

Comment: nodemon has many bugs (as I know). Go with `pm2`. I can post pm2 code if you are planning to go with it.

Comment: I'll check it out. That shouldn't effect the stylesheet though correct? 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

That's my sheet, do I need to restructure the location? My folder is desktop/projects/folder/app/index.html

Comment: Corey, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Your express server is serving out of a directory named `public`, but BrowserSync is serving `app`. Try renaming `public` to `app` in server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
var router = express.Router();

    app.use(express.static('app'));
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    app.listen(3001, function() {
        console.log("I'm Listening...")
    })
```

By the way, Gulp is *not a server*. It doesn't make sense to say it defaults to a port. BrowserSync, a live-reloading server, is being run by Gulp, which is a simple task runner.

Comment: Okay Steven, I've got that changed to app, that has helped. Now express is running, it's just not picking up my style.css.

When i run gulp, it opens a browser to localhost:7000 (thats listed as the port in a task). Would it not be loading a style sheet because its pointed to localhost:5000?

Comment: I mean honestly, I would just ditch Express and use BrowserSync. I'm not sure where ports 5000 and 7000 are coming from, but you've got two separate server setups here, and you should probably settle on BrowserSync for development.

Comment: Okay, and that will be able to communicate with Mongo instead of using Express? That's where my confusion is. I guess I'm thinking Express is being required right now? I've got a node server running, via express. Should i delete server.js and focus somewhere else? I just want to get to editing my index.html wtih angular/etc.

Comment: nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting. I keep getting a throw error in module.js:341. Error: Cannot find module 'C:\users\corey|desktop\projects\folder\server.js' It's only my css not showing up now when index.html loads...ideas?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you were trying to use Mongo at the same time. In that case, yes, you should try to proxy browserSync to your express server a la @ShanShan's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `browser-sync` in [proxy mode](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy):

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "localhost:3001"
    });
});
```

Now, run server.js first and then gulp, and you'll have only one server running (browser-sync will give you the URL to use).

Comment: nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting. I keep getting a throw error in module.js:341. 

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\users\corey|desktop\projects\folder\server.js'

Answer (score 0):

I think https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-express is the exact solution for you.

Comment: I downloaded the packages and tried getting this up but to no success. I keep getting errors, etc. Is there a way Supun I could show you my files? This is my second day js, i've gotten far, but stuck on express for hours now

Comment: I can start my node server, run gulp, it opens up my browser to localhost:7000 with my index.html...everything great, but css not working

Comment: nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting. I keep getting a throw error in module.js:341. Error: Cannot find module 'C:\users\corey|desktop\projects\folder\server.js' 

It's only my css not showing up now when index.html loads...ideas?